# ExtJS Can not display Ext.panel.Panel's html properly

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, panel, xtemplate

I've a class inherit from `Ext.grid.Panel` and using a method inside this class to display a `panel` which includes two items: a `listtoolbar` class and a `Ext.XTemplate` staff.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.BGrid', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.AGrid', //This class extends from 'Ext.grid.Panel'
    requires: [
            ...
            'Ext.layout.container.VBox',
            'MyApp.view.base.ListToolbar'
    ],
    getDashBoardTpl: function () {
        var me = this;

        return [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                // html: 'so what?', // Displays the text; See -Img 01
                // html: me.dashTpl(), // Displays as [object object]; See -Img 02
                layout: {type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch', pack: 'center'},
                items:
                    [
                        {
                            xtype: 'listtoolbar', //Display nothing!
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            name: 'dashtpl',
                            flex: 1,
                            // html: 'so WHat?' //Display nothing!
                            html: me.dashTpl() //Display nothing!
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

It can not displaying panel's items; `listtoolbar` and `dashtpl`'s html. instead of that it works when the `html` tag is using upper panel. Just the thing is displays `[Object] [Object]` when `dashTpl` function used in first panel.

Here is dashTpl();

```
dashTpl: function(){
        var tpl= new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">' +
                '<div class="dashTpl">'+
                    '<table style="width:100%;height:80px;text-align:center" >'+
                        '<tr style="width:100%;">'+
                            '<td style="box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px #BDBDBD;background-color:#EEEEEE;width:20%">'+
                                '<a>'+
                                    '<span style="font-size:24px;"><b style="color: #8000FF;">5,875.00</b></span><br/>'+
                                    '<div>'+
                                        '<b style="color: #6E6E6E;font-size:14px;">€</b>' +
```

What could be the reason for this? Thanks in advice.

Here is [Img 01](https://prnt.sc/i8n9ok) and [Img 02](https://prnt.sc/i8n9yx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nuri, In your code you are setting [`html`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-html) using [`Ext.XTemplate`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-tpl) inside of [`panel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html), this is not right way to use `html` config.

> If you want to use [`html`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-html) config in `panel` then you need to set tpl like below example

```
html:'<table class="x-date-table"><tbody><tr><th>SNo.</th><th>Date</th><th>Event</th><th>Venue Details</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>12 February</td><td>Waltz with Strauss</td><td>Main Hall</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>24 March</td><td>The Obelisks</td><td>West Wing</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>15 February</td><td>Kolidoscop</td><td>Reception Hall</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>24 March</td><td>The data center</td><td>UDM</td></tr></tbody></table>'
```

> If you want to use [`tpl/Ext.XTemplate`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-tpl) config in `panel` then you need to set tpl like below example

```
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    //start table
    '<table class="x-date-table">',
    //Header of my table
    '<tr>',
    '<th>SNo.</th>',
    '<th>Date</th>',
    '<th>Event</th>',
    '<th>Venue Details</th>',
    '</tr>',
    //Looping insdie tpl for creating multiple row depend on data
    '<tpl for=".">', //Start loop tpl
    '<tr>',
    '<td>{#}</td>',
    '<td>{date}</td>',
    '<td>{event}</td>',
    '<td>{venue}</td>',
    '</tr>',
    '</tpl>', //End loop tpl
    '</table>' //Close table
)
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ckc)**, I have created a demo using same as mentioned above. I hope this will help you or guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        //Array of data for testing/example
        var data = [{
            date: '12 February',
            event: 'Waltz with Strauss',
            venue: 'Main Hall'
        }, {
            date: '24 March',
            event: 'The Obelisks',
            venue: 'West Wing'
        }, {
            date: '15 February',
            event: 'Kolidoscop',
            venue: 'Reception Hall'
        }, {
            date: '24 March',
            event: 'The data center',
            venue: 'UDM'
        }];
        //Panel show data with XTemplate
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            fullscreen: true,
            title: 'Example of XTemplate in Panel',
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                //start table
                '<table class="x-date-table">',
                //Header of my table
                '<tr>',
                '<th>SNo.</th>',
                '<th>Date</th>',
                '<th>Event</th>',
                '<th>Venue Details</th>',
                '</tr>',
                //Looping insdie tpl for creating multiple row depend on data
                '<tpl for=".">', //Start loop tpl
                '<tr>',
                '<td>{#}</td>',
                '<td>{date}</td>',
                '<td>{event}</td>',
                '<td>{venue}</td>',
                '</tr>',
                '</tpl>', //End loop tpl
                '</table>' //Close table
            ),
            data: data
        });

        /*This function will create html base on data and return
         * @param {Array} arr contain of data/records
         * @return {String/HTML}
         */
        function doGetHtml(arr) {
            let html = `<table class="x-date-table"><tr><th>SNo.</th><th>Date</th><th>Event</th><th>Venue Details</th></tr>`;

            arr.forEach((item, index) => {
                html += `<tr><td>${index+1}</td><td>${item.date}</td><td>${item.event}</td><td>${item.venue}</td></tr>`;
            });
            return `${html}</table>`
        }

        //Panel show data with HTMl
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            margin: '20 0 0 0',
            fullscreen: true,
            title: 'Example of HMTL in Panel',
            html: doGetHtml(data)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Dear @Narendra Jadhav I've understand the situation with `tpl` but here I'm facing with rendering problem as well. Above inside `getDashBoardTpl ` function I can render `config` within a `panel` but when I create items to this `panel` it's not displaying. i thought that reason could be `layout` adjusments but non of configuration worked. Why this could be, any idea?

Comment: I've tried to add 2 `textfield` items to parent `panel` but they did not appeared as well.

Comment: @NuriEngin Ok can just let me know  from where you are calling this function `getDashBoardTpl` ?

Comment: Through inherited class `AGrid`. There is a function which includes a panel;  `xtype: 'panel', ...,  items: {xtype: 'panel',
                   name: 'dashboardtpl',
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    bodyPadding: 20,
                    flex: 1,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    layout: {align: 'stretch', type: 'anchor', pack: 'start'},
                    html: me.getDashBoardTpl()`

Comment: can you please create [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)? so I can try to check/debug actual problem.

Comment: Here is the [Fiddle] (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor|fiddle/2cl4). I couldn't run it but you can see whole picture in it.

Comment: Ok let me check this fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164403/discussion-between-narendra-jadhav-and-nuri-engin).

Comment: did you got the screen shot?

Comment: Dear @NarendraJadhav. All works now and pretty well =) Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @NuriEngin Can you just let me know how did you resolve ?

Comment: Sure! Firstly I had the mistake of implementing a `panel` within `html` config! So I've moved main function of *getDashboardTpl* and reconfigured it as adding `items` config and calling `html` config within items. So I've created this `listtoolbar` panel and getDashBoardTpl panel. Of course configured tpl thorugh your explanation =)